# Creating dummy variable using pandas or statsmodel for interaction of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, patsy

I have a data frame like this:

```
Index ID  Industry  years_spend       asset
6646  892         4            4  144.977037
2347  315        10            8  137.749138
7342  985         1            5  104.310217
137    18         5            5  156.593396
2840  381        11            2  229.538828
6579  883        11            1  171.380125
1776  235         4            7  217.734377
2691  361         1            2  148.865341
815   110        15            4  233.309491
2932  393        17            5  187.281724
```

I want to create dummy variables for Industry X years_spend which creates `len(df.Industry.value_counts()) * len(df.years_spend.value_counts())` varaible, for example d_11_4 = 1 for all rows that has industry==1 and years spend=4 otherwise d_11_4 = 0. Then I can use these vars for some regression works.

I know I can make groups like what I want using df.groupby(['Industry','years_spend']) and I know I can create such variable for one column using `patsy` syntax in `statsmodels`:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

mod = smf.ols("income ~   C(Industry)", data=df).fit()
```

but If I want to do with 2 columns I get an error that:
`IndexError: tuple index out of range`

How can I do that with pandas or using some function inside statsmodels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this where you have to first create a calculated field that encapsulates the `Industry` and `years_spend`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Industry': [4, 3, 11, 4, 1, 1], 'years_spend': [4, 5, 8, 4, 4, 1]})
df['industry_years'] = df['Industry'].astype('str') + '_' + df['years_spend'].astype('str')  # this is the calculated field
```

Here's what the `df` looks like:

```
   Industry  years_spend industry_years
0         4            4            4_4
1         3            5            3_5
2        11            8           11_8
3         4            4            4_4
4         1            4            1_4
5         1            1            1_1
```

Now you can apply [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['industry_years'])
```

That'll get you what you want :)

Comment: thanks I figured it out using for loops and boolean indexing but you show me a more pythonic way.Do you have any idea how should i include those dummies in my statsmodels regression? should I use something like ` "".join(['+industry{}'.format(x) for x in range(10) ])` or there is a better way.

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to create industry_years column and then use ("income ~ C(industry) ") , data = df) creates dummies for the regression.

Comment: @Mehdi, sorry, I haven't used `statsmodels` for modeling, but I would imagine you could just put all your independent variables into a list variable (using `df.columns` and dropping the y column), then build a string using the idea you gave earlier: `"+".join(list_of_indep_vars)`, and then creating your model with `"income ~ string_you_just_built"`. Of course, this is assuming the way to define a regression formula in `statsmodels` is `y ~ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 ... x_n`.

Answer (score 7):

Using patsy syntax it's just:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

mod = smf.ols("income ~ C(Industry):C(years_spend)", data=df).fit()
```

The `:` character means "interaction"; you can also generalize this to interactions of more than two items (`C(a):C(b):C(c)`), interactions between numerical and categorical values, etc. You might find the [patsy docs useful](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).