# Implementing user inputs into neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have some theoretical questions along with my original question.

I am very new to Keras, and am having some logical questions. The first question is regarding the train, test etc.
I come from using Sci-kit learn and usually use the test_train_split library to do this (I am assuming I can do the same here?)

My next question would be the transformation of the features and labels. From my understanding so far, we cannot feed strings 
into the neural network, so some sort of nomalization would have to be done.

I learned either tokenization or dummy variables for categorical variables, normalization should be done for the numerical values. My question with this is: there are 5 columns (2 categorical and 3 numerical) in a feature vector. Can I create dummy variables for the 2 categorical and then normalize the ENTIRE feature vector?

After this, my question would in the code below about the input_shape(x, y). The example code below is from image recognization. Say that I want to use my own data set, will I have to know the input_shape beforehand and define it that way? Or is that something that the model can learn itself?

My last question would be in this: say that the features vector is composed of variables a, b, c, and d. How can I have the user enter their value for a, b, c, and d and have the model give an output? In the example, the model was loaded in from a CSV into a dataframe and then I spit that data into testing and training for features and labels. In this instance, do I need to store the users variables into a dataframe in order for the model to predict output?

The code I am referring to is for images, but my use case will not be images rather integers. Code:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import models
from keras import layers

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

model = model.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer= 'rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=64)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
```

Any help would be great as I am quite new to this!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote helpful answers and mark an answer as accepted if you find it sufficient to solve your problem! See the help section on [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Of course, if you want to wait and see if anyone else has a different, better solution then by all means. :)

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Classification or regression? Second categorical inputs are normally encoded - either embedding or one-hot-encoding. You don't feed the raw integers into a net. Lets say I'm classifying between cat, dog, and car. If cat - 0, dog - 1, car - 2, the network infers that cat < dog < car, which is not true! OHE solves this problem with cat - [1, 0, 0], dog - [0, 1, 0], car - [0, 0, 1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I come from using Sci-kit learn and usually use the test_train_split library to do this (I am assuming I can do the same here?)

Yes! Shouldn't matter at all

> From my understanding so far, we cannot feed strings into the neural network, so some sort of nomalization would have to be done.

Correct. The neural network is just a whole lot of mathematical operations on numbers. That being said, you can represent strings as numbers (Google word2vec for more info)

> [T]here are 5 columns (2 categorical and 3 numerical) in a feature vector. Can I create dummy variables for the 2 categorical and then normalize the ENTIRE feature vector?

I would assume that by categorical, you mean classes? The classes are never to go into the network as features. Then classifying would make no sense whatsoever. If you just want to do prediction you could just look at [`model.predict`](https://keras.io/models/model/).

> The example code below is from image recognization. Say that I want to use my own data set, will I have to know the input_shape beforehand and define it that way? Or is that something that the model can learn itself?

Neural networks are bunches of matrix multiplications. You would need to provide *some* of the dimensions. It doesn't need a prior knowledge of the batch_size (you could give it, though), but the other dimensions are important: that is, the number of features in the input layer. The `input_shape = (10000,)` in the code is just short hand for `input_shape = (10000,None)`, where `None` would be where you could have put the batch size (number of datapoints). The `10000` is the number of features, in this case.

> How can I have the user enter their value for a, b, c, and d and have the model give an output?

Just note that the point is that you don't know the outputs beforehand.

```
oneToFive=input("Enter 5 numbers separated by commas")
oneToFive=oneToFive.split(",")
oneToFive=[np.float32(c) for c in oneToFive]
model.predict(x=np.array(oneToFive))
```

---

I would recommend that you look into the theory behind this. Just blindly running around will probably be very annoying because you'd have a very hard time getting good results. And even if you got good results, they might often not be as good as you think. One place to read would be [Ian Goodfellow's book on deep learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/).

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! In regards to the 3rd yellow paragraph you responded with, wouldn't I create dummy variables for the 2 columns of type "string" and normalize the rest of the columns (of class "float") between [0,1]? And for the input_shape, should I find the input_shape of the feature vector, and place that as the input_shape for the first layer? I am reading "Deep Learning with Python" by Francois Chollet, so I am learning the logic as I go!

Comment: @rmahesh I'm not sure what you mean by dummy variables for what columns? I'm really confused. For the `input_shape`: it is convention in tensorflow (and keras) to use the first axis (vertical) as batch input and then the second (horisontal) as the feature axis. That is if you do `np.shape(input_data)` you'd get `(num_batches, num_features)`. However when you specify `input_shape` you should do it without the batch size, so you just throw a `None` on the end as I wrote.

Comment: @rmahesh the input data only have to be numbers. If you have text data, then you should look into the conventions on working with that. I have very little experience with this, and keywords would be "word2vec" and "bag of words". If the data, however, are in string type, but still numbers, then it's okay to just typecast them to floats, yes. They do not have to be between `[0,1]` though?

Comment: The dummy variables would be only for the columns containing categorical variables. So if I were to have Monday-Friday as the range in which
one of the columns would go through and were to numerate them 1-5, 5 would be weighted greater than 1 where there is no hierarchy in reality. 
In pandas, I have used this in the past: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: For the input_shape, say than X is the features stored in a dataframe I read in. Say I were to do np.shape(X) and got (500,10). When I load this 
into the first later of the neural network, I would set the input_shape as (500,None)? Thanks for your patience as I am going through this.

Comment: @rmahesh you would do `input_shape=(10,)` in the case you have 10 features per sample. I would assume that in the case you presented where `X.shape` is `(500,10)` that you have 500 samples and 10 features. I’m still not understanding what you mean by dummy and categorical values. Could you provide a small example dataset with code?

Comment: That makes sense I was thinking that the (500,10) referred to rows and columns! As for creating dummy variables for columns with categorical data, this stackoverflow post does a splendid job explaining what is done and how/why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056401/creating-dummy-variable-using-pandas-or-statsmodel-for-interaction-of-two-column                           I have read that tokenizing the data works as well for strings in neural networks, so I am guessing the logic is somewhat similar?

Comment: @rmahesh `(500,10)` is the rows and columns respectively, yes. So you are talking about the headers of the dataset?

Comment: I am trying to understand the logic of 'input_shape'. Please correct me if I am mistaken, but I feed 10 into the first layer for 'input_shape' if I run 'X.shape' and get (500,10)?

Comment: You have 500 observations with 10 features. Say you have conducted a survey with 10 questions and 500 people participated. The first row of the matrix `X` would be 10 the answers of the first person. The nth row of `X` would be the 10 answers of the nth person.

Comment: Okay I think this makes sense thank you so much for your patience in explaining these concepts to me!